# problemas con el puerto serial utilizando manjaro

Tags: pyserial

estoy intentando utilizar comunicacion serial corro el siguiente codigo

import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')

pero me genera el siguiente error

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

he instalado todo los paquetes y ya no se que hacer